# MySQL Query not correct

Tags: mysql, sql

having an issue with my MySQL query that I can not figure out...

I'm trying to get a count of how many rows are in the table "questions" that are not in the table "answers" where the user_id matches

This is my MySQL at the moment and it returns 0 rows even though it should return 13...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM questions 
LEFT OUTER JOIN answers 
  ON questions.quest_id = answers.ans_question 
JOIN users 
  ON answers.ans_user = users.user_id 
WHERE answers.ans_question IS null 
  and questions.quest_level <= (SELECT user_level 
                                FROM users 
                                WHERE username = 'chris3spice') 
  and answers.ans_user = (SELECT user_id 
                          FROM users 
                          WHERE username = 'chris3spice');
```

This is my original query which returns how many are in questions that aren't in answers... but it doesn't take into account user_id but it does take into account the user_level so no issues there...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM questions 
LEFT OUTER JOIN answers 
  ON questions.quest_id = answers.ans_question 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users 
  ON answers.ans_user = users.user_id 
WHERE answers.ans_question IS null 
  and questions.quest_level <= (SELECT user_level 
                                FROM users 
                                WHERE username = 'chris3spice');
```

Here are my tables for reference

quest_id-----quest_text------quest_ans

1_***_*__*_*__*_*__***blah****_*__*_*___**_blah

...

14_***_*__*_*____***blah****_*__*_*___**_blah

.

.

ans_id-----ans_user------ans_quest

1_***_*__*_*__*_*__***1****_*__*_*___**_1

...

14_***_*__*_*____***2****_*__*_*___**_13

.

.
user_id-----user_name

1_***_*__*_*___**_chris3spice

2_***_*__*_*___**_testing

Comment: Try breaking your query down into parts to see which is causing the problem.  Just do `select count(*) from questions left join answers on questions.quest_id = answers.ans_question where answers.ans_question is null` and see if you get what you expect for that part.

Comment: The _problem_ with your first query is `answers.ans_user = ...`. When you are LEFT JOINing and looking for unmatched records, **answers.ans_user** will be NULL and thus false.

Comment: I've tried breaking it down and I can get some results... I guess its with the LEFT JOIN that is killing me...

So I need to get the answers that match a user id... then from there I need to get the questions from the questions table that are not already in the answers table where the user id matches...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - I moved some of your logic around to isolate the LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM users
JOIN questions
  ON questions.quest_level <= users.user_level
LEFT OUTER JOIN answers 
  ON questions.quest_id = answers.ans_question
    AND answers.ans_user = users.user_id
WHERE answers.ans_question IS null 
  AND users.username = 'chris3spice';
```

Comment: I believe that did it, I did not know you could use AND to combine the joins... Thank you very much